# include a file based on date range

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to display store hours based on the date range.  I need to display normal hours except between June 15 and September 1 when summer hours are used.  I currently have both in my code (below) and I simply comment one line.  Can someone help me automate this?

```
<?php
//include ("content/summer_hours.inc");
include ("content/normal_hours.inc");
?>
```

Comment: Just add an if statement that checks the dates and includes the proper file.

Comment: Why put the store hours in separate include files?

Comment: @crush -- I know it isn't necessary, but I like to keep most of my html components outside of my php script for cleaner code in my templates.

Answer (score 0):

Off the proverbial cuff...

```
$june15=strtotime("15 June ".date('Y'));
$sep1=strtotime("1 September ".date('Y'));
$now=time();
if ($now > $june15 && $now < $sep1){
  include ("content/summer_hours.inc");
}
else{
  include ("content/normal_hours.inc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that compares the day of the year, and sees if it falls between the days of the year that you are looking for. Might be more efficient. There's probably an even faster way of doing this.

```
$year = date('Y'); //Get the current year
$today = date('z'); //Get the day of the year.
$june15 = 166; //166th day of year
$sept01 = 244; //244th day of year
$isleap = (($year & 3) == 0 && (($year % 25) != 0 || ($year & 15) == 0)); //Is it a leap year.

if ($today > $june15 + $isleap && $today < $sept01 + $isleap) {
    include ("content/summer_hours.inc");
} else {
    include ("content/normal_hours.inc");
}
```

Comment: very nice!  Thanks to both of you.